# Flutter webview plugin - enable pinch zoom

Tags: flutter

i am new to flutter. I could able to create a web view using flutter webview plugin. but I could not able to zoom(pinch zoom ) the website. any solution to this?

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebviewScaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text("Hi"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),


            onPressed: () => scanbarcode(),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 50,),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home,color: Colors.white,),
            onPressed: (){
              flutterWebviewPlugin.reloadUrl("http://www.google.com");
            },
          ),

        ],
      ),
      url: urlString,
      withZoom: true,
      withJavascript: true,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
this.webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
this.webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
```